# How to increment the transform position faster and smoothly

Tags: javascript, css, math, dom, transform

I am changing translate value and incrementing it, but it seems that the value is incrementing like : - 0, -5, -10, -15, -20 because I have multiplied the difference of the mouse moved and the actual mouse position, so my question is, how can I make the speed of increment faster without multiplying it, like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15?

Here is the example code: https://jsfiddle.net/dy1vk40f/1/

```js
scrollcontainer.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();

  const x = e.pageX;
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(scrollcontainer);
  const matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.transform);

  const walk = x - startX; // startX MEANS THE POSITION MOUSE IS CLICKED for dragging
  scrollcontainer.style.userSelect = 'none';
  scrollcontainer.style.transform = `translate3d(${matrix.m41 + (walk * 5)}px, 0px, 0px)`;
  startX = e.pageX;

});
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add HTML and CSS to make a [mcve]

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle project for the same problem, hope it helps, I have update the description

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is possible. You want it to move faster but you still want it to increment by 1. The only other option is to increase the rate at which the mousemove event is called, but that's probably beyond your control. Perhaps you could explain why you want it to move faster and why steps of more than 1 are not acceptable?

Comment: Why jsfiddle? Just post it here using the snippet editor. As long as you do not use localStorage it runs here too

Comment: @XylemFlow, basically the mousemove event when move from a position to other, it only provides a very small number, so if I add the number to the transform property it will only make it move a little. I want to implement a method in which when the mouse is clicked and dragged I want to show image carousels, but I am unable to achieve it

Comment: @mplungjan, the HTML is quite bigger, so I have created a separate jsfiddle file

Comment: OK, I understand why you may want it to move quicker than the mouse, but why is the current solution of multiplying by 5 not acceptable? It looks fine to me.

Comment: @XylemFlow, yeah so basically the way it keeps adding number after a gap is not something that I want. I kind of giving a very little glitchy view that I don't like. I have also looked in some other websites image scrolls and they are increamenting faster and smoothly on the transform property. Maybe I am not sure on how to do like them. Any help please